# Finding all ng-model elements of a particular child elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written on directive I just want all the ng-model elements inside the element where the directive is placed
This is my html element with `loggerhelp`  directive

```
<input type="text" loggerhelp  />
```

This is my directive

```
    angular
 .module('app').directive('loggerhelp', loggerhelp);


loggerhelp($mdDialog) {
        var Popupdirective = {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: popupController
        }
        return Popupdirective
        function popupController(scope, element, attr) {
// Here i want all the child ng-model elements.
            console.log(element)
            alert();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you want `ng-model` of all nested `child elements` also, ?
like: if you have 100 `ng-model` inside 1 element , `<div loggerhelp> <span ng-model='prop1'></span>......<span ng-model='prop100'></span></div>`, aur you only want the current div `ng-model` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [searching by attribute](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) like `element.find("[ng-model]")`? `element` is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches so [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and the selectors should work for you.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  
}])
.directive('loggerhelp', function loggerhelp() {
        var loggerhelpDirective = {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: loggerhelpController
        }
        return loggerhelpDirective
        function loggerhelpController(scope, element, attr) {
            var innerElementsWithNgModel = element.find("[ng-model]");
            console.log(innerElementsWithNgModel.length);
            console.log(angular.element(innerElementsWithNgModel[2]).attr('ng-model'));
            
            //so now you have an array with all the elements that have ng-model attr
            //you can attach event handler function for blur 
            innerElementsWithNgModel.on('blur', function(){
                var ngModelAttr = angular.element(this).attr('ng-model');
                //we can evaluate this now using $eval
                if (ngModelAttr){
                  console.log(scope.$eval(ngModelAttr));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">

    <div loggerhelp>
      <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.model1"  />
      <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.model2"  />
      <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.model3"  />
      <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.model4"  />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1:** Working snippet to illustrate how it works.

**UPDATE 2:** Now we can attach event handler function for blur event using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [evaluate the attribute using `$eval()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look on the updated and the code snippet attached - it successfully finds the elements with `ng-model` attribute inside the element on which directive is applied. Of course, if you are applying the directive on the input like `<input type="text" loggerhelp  />` this will not work because this input doesn't contain nested elements.

Comment: Ya its working,but can i get the model scope binded inside the directive means console.log with whatever value as soon as the textbox is blur

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by fourth parameter of directive , i.e `NgModelController`, [Read doc.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Code should be like:

```
 link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log(element);
        console.log(ngModel.$viewValue);
      }, 0)
    }
```

See this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyv4fr84/)